# DM'ing on reaction Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

This is what I have so far:

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == MESSAGE_ID:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, bot.guilds)
        if payload.emoji.name == "EMOJI":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="ROLE_NAME")
        if role is not None:
```

I would like to make it so on the last if statement it would dm the user but due to on_raw_reaction_add not taking the user parameter I appear to be clueless on the matter. Any form of support would be appreciated.

Comment: The [payload](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent) does have a `member` property. You can use that to DM the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written by [@dumbPotato21](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5055190/dumbpotato21) [`payload`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent) has `member` atributte. So DM'ing someone would look like this:

```py
await payload.member.send("HELLO")
```